# Rails: Dynamic form generation from the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

I've been scratching my brain (kinda painful, wouldn't advise it) trying to figure out a way to pull this off, but I haven't been able to come up with anything that really seems feasible.

The idea is this: I have a page that allows you to create an event. This event could be anything from a wedding to a marathon or fund raiser. Different events need to have a form specific to that event type, e.g. the wedding event needs the name of the bride, groom, address, receptions, etc.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to allow them to select an event type, and then go to localhost:3000/events/create(/:event_type) and have that view load in the correct form fields.

My original thought was to have event types stored in a database with each form stored as JSON, but this just seems more complicated than I'd think necessary.

Any ideas?

Here's routes.rb so far:

```
  get 'my_events/', to: 'events#index', as: :events
  get 'events/create', to: 'events#create', as: :new_event
  match 'events/new', to: 'events#new', as: :post_new_event, via: :post
  get 'event/:slug', to: 'events#show', as: :show_event

  root 'static#index'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks' }
```

And the events controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @events = Event.all()
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new()
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find_by slug: params[:slug]
  end

  def delete

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a form with tags to match any number of columns without knowing the column names like this

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
  <% @event.attributes.each do |k,v| %>
    <% unless k == 'id' %> #in the case of an edit form, the id should not be changable
      <p>
      <%= f.label k.to_sym %><br> #get the name of the column, put it into a symbol
      <%= f.text_field k.to_sym %> #same as above, will put the matching value in if it exists
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Though this may not be suited for how your model appears to be set up, a single Event database that can hold any event. This would work better if you had a specific database for each type.

To go in to detail on how I would see this working for you...
Your planned route `/events/create/:event_type` would work

in your new action in the controller

```
def new
  if params[:event_type] == 'wedding'
    @event = Wedding.new #would need to do the same for each event type
  end                    #a model/database for each different type of event
end
```

However if event is a parent Event database to a child event type, you may be able to make it work, though I'm not familiar enough with relational databases in Ruby on Rails to say how.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common pattern.  On your edit/new form(or modal), you need to have a javascript handler on your event_id field.  When it changes, you do an ajax request to your server to get the valid event_types for that event so that you may populate the event_types input control.

I would strongly discourage doing any client side storage (hard coding) of the event_types as this design will not allow for easy addition of future events.